# SQL statement that takes all the rows apart from those who's attribute count is 0

Tags: php, sql

I am populating an array in PHP using data from a database.

Here is the statement. I'll try to explain it afterwards:

```
SELECT Country.*, Cyclist.ISO_id
FROM Country 
LEFT JOIN Cyclist ON Cyclist.ISO_id = Country.ISO_id 
WHERE country_name IS NOT null
```

I am selecting all attributes from the table Country, and the country ID from the Cyclist table

I am reading from Country, and joining Cyclist based on the ID of the country (i.e. if a cyclist has the same country ID as the country ID found in Country).

I am getting these countries's attributes if the country name is defined in the database.

Country table:

```
ISO_id:AFG country_name:Afghanistan gold:0 total:0
```

Cyclist table

```
name: John Watson Height:178 ISO_id:AFG
```

The statement however doesnt work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Step 1: decide which DBMS you are actually using and tag appropriately. Step 2: explain the problem. "doesn't work" is not explaining the issue.

Comment: When populating the PHP array with the database data, countries that have null as a country name will still appear in the array.

Comment: I think you are looking for INNER JOIN which would limit the Country to those that are also in the Cyclist table. Currently you are getting all countries, regardless if there is an associated cyclist.

Comment: All countries have a country name (no countries will be null). However if the user enters a blank string when looking for a country, the array will still be populated with all attributes being null. So I am trying to find a way to filter out of my array the records that have a country of null, as this would signify that the country does not exist, and thus should not be included in the array.

Comment: well then this isn't a SQL Server or MySQL focused question, it's on how you are building your array which you haven't posted. Also, remove the tag of the erroneous DBMS. Perhaps you are looking for `WHERE country_name = 'someUserInput'`. Or, handle the logic on the application side

Comment: Is the country actually NULL, or is it an empty string?  Try `WHERE country_name > ''`

Comment: The country, along with all other attributes are null, not empty.

Comment: I agree with @scsimon This is a PHP array question, not a SQL question.

Comment: Right, will post in the appropriate place. Thank you#